# how to concatenate one to many records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `User` and `UserRoles` in sql server. `User` table  has basic user information e.g. `UserId,Name` etc and `UserRoles` has columns like `UserId,RoleName`. There is one to many relationship between these two tables i.e. one User can have multiple roles.

User

```
UserId  Name
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

UserRoles

```
UserId  Rolename
1       Manager
1       Event Organiser
2       Supervisor
2       Employee
2       Some otherRole
```

I need to write a query in sql which will return like following. i.e concatenate one to many records into a single string

```
UserId  Roles
1       Manager,Event Organiser
2       Supervisor,Employee,Some otherRole
```

Comment: Here's a more modern way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236851/one-to-many-sql-select-concatenated-into-single-row

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use Below 2 SQL Function

**[XML Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)**- For Concatenation

**[Stuff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)** For Comma separation

```
select UserId,
    stuff((select ',' + t2.Rolename
     from UserRoles t2 where t1.UserId = t2.UserId
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') Roles
from UserRoles t1
group by UserId
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14aff/1)**

Comment: Luv, great answer - typo in Concatenation. Sorry I can't edit I don't have the rep for that small a change.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @t1 table(UserId int,name varchar(20))
insert into @t1 values(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')
--select * from @t1
Declare @t table(UserId int,Rolename varchar(20))
insert into @t values(1,'Manager'),(1,'Event Organiser'),(2,'Supervisor'),(2,'Employee'),(2,'Some otherRole')

select 
userid,
stuff((select ','+ Rolename from @t b where a.UserId=b.UserId for xml path('')),1,1,'') [Roles]
 from @t1 a
```