# One-to-Many SQL SELECT concatenated into single row

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, subquery, string-aggregation

I'm using Postgres and I have the following schemes.

**Orders**

```
| id |    status   |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |  delivered  |
|  2 | recollected |
```

**Comments**

```
| id |   text  | user | order |
|----|---------|------|-------|
|  1 | texto 1 |  10  |   20  |
|  2 | texto 2 |  20  |   20  |
```

So, in this case, an order can have many comments.

I need to iterate over the orders and get something like this:

```
| id |    status   |    comments    |
|----|-------------|----------------|
|  1 |  delivered  | text 1, text 2 |
|  2 | recollected |                |
```

I tried to use LEFT JOIN but it didn't work

```sql
SELECT
    Order.id,
    Order.status,
    "Comment".text
FROM  "Order" 
LEFT JOIN "Comment" ON Order.id = "Comment"."order"
```

it returns this:

```
| id |    status   | text   |
|----|-------------|--------|
|  1 |  delivered  | text 1 |
|  1 |  delivered  | text 2 |
|  2 |  recollected|        |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - you just need aggregation:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.status,
    STRING_AGG(c.text, ',') comments
FROM  "Order" o
LEFT JOIN "Comment" c ON p.id = c."order"
GROUP BY o.id, o.status
```

I would strongly recommend against having a table (and/or a column) called `order`: because it conflicts with a language keyword. I would also recommend avoiding quoted identifiers as much as possible - they make the queries longer to write, for no benefit.

Note that you can also use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.status,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(c.text, ',') FROM "Comment" c WHERE c."order" = p.id) comments
FROM  "Order" o
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work with `LEFT JOIN` and aggregate after the join. But it's **typically more efficient** to aggregate first and join later.

If most or all rows in `"Comment"` are involved:

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.status, c.comments
FROM   "Order" o
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT "order" AS id, string_agg(text, ', ') AS comments
   FROM   "Comment"
   GROUP  BY 1
   )  c USING (id);
```

Indexes won't matter, while most rows have to be read anyway.

For only a small percentage of rows (like, if you have a selective filter on `"Order"`):

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.status, c.comments
FROM   "Order" o
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(text, ', ')  AS comments
   FROM   "Comment"
   WHERE  "order" = o.id
   )  c ON true
WHERE  <some_selective_filter>;
```

In this case, be sure to have an **index** on `("Comment"."order")`, or more specialized, a covering index including `text`:

```
 CREATE INDEX foo ON "Comment" ("order") INCLUDE (text);
```

Related:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)
- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)
- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684)

Aside: Consider legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres. In particular, don't (ab-)use completely reserved [SQL keywords like `ORDER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifier. Much clearer and less potential for sneaky errors. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)